symfony 7, Twig, AssetMapper: assets are served fine on dev, but 404 in prod
I am naively trying to learn AssetMapper and follow the instructions but I must be doing something wrong. In my local development environment, it's working flawlessly. In the prod environment on the server I plan to use for production, I have run php bin/console asset-map:compile per the documentation:
php bin/console asset-map:compile

 // Compiling and writing asset files to public                                                                         

 // Compiled 14 assets                                                                                                  

 // Manifest written to public/assets/manifest.json                                                                     

 // Import map data written to public/assets/importmap.json.                                                            

 // Entrypoint metadata written for 1 entrypoints (app). 

but when I view the page in the browser, the css and js and image assets are 404. Looking at the img tage rendered by the Twig function {{ asset('images/logo.png') }}, we see this src attribute pointing to a versioned asset:
src="/assets/images/logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png"
and that's a 404 error. But when I look for the file at that path on the filesystem, it's right there:
ls -l public/assets/images/

-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 151251 Jun  5 16:05 logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png

So file is there, the permissions are OK, but it's 404.
Compare to the dev machine, where I am running the symfony development server. All my assets are served just fine. That same img tag looks like this:
curl -s https://127.0.0.1:8001/ | grep logo
            <img [...]src="/assets/images/logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png"

but when I look for it on the filesystem, from the project root folder:
ls -l public/assets/images/logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png
ls: cannot access 'public/assets/images/logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png': No such file or directory

and in fact, there is nothing in the public folder except index.php.
So, on the one hand, in the dev environment, files are served that don't exist at their filesystem path to which the browser's being pointed, while in the prod environment, the reverse:  files that do exist at the indicated path are 404.
How can this be? I begin to wonder if it has to do with Apache and the rewrite rules that I copied verbatim from the Symfony Apache pack and put in my vhost config. But I have used these or very similar rewrite rules with other frameworks and applications for years, and never had this problem. So I am well and truly perplexed.
UPDATE per the commment below:
$  php bin/console config:dump framework asset_mapper
Default configuration for extension with alias: "framework" at path "asset_mapper"

Asset Mapper configuration
asset_mapper:
    enabled:              true

# Directories that hold assets that should be in the mapper. Can be a simple array of an array of ["path/to/assets": "namespace"]
paths:

    # Example:
    # - assets/

    # Prototype
    namespace:            ~

# Array of glob patterns of asset file paths that should not be in the asset mapper
excluded_patterns:    []

    # Examples:
    # - '*/assets/build/*'
    # - '*/*_.scss'

# If true, any files starting with "." will be excluded from the asset mapper
exclude_dotfiles:     true

# If true, a "dev server" will return the assets from the public directory (true in "debug" mode only by default)
server:               false

# The public path where the assets will be written to (and served from when "server" is true)
public_prefix:        /assets/

# Behavior if an asset cannot be found when imported from JavaScript or CSS files - e.g. "import './non-existent.js'". "strict" means an exception is thrown, "warn" means a warning is logged, "ignore" means the import is left as-is.
missing_import_mode:  warn # One of "strict"; "warn"; "ignore"

# Key-value pair of file extensions set to their mime type.
extensions:

    # Example:
    # .zip:                application/zip

    # Prototype
    extension:            ~

# The path of the importmap.php file.
importmap_path:       '%kernel.project_dir%/importmap.php'

# The importmap name that will be used to load the polyfill. Set to false to disable.
importmap_polyfill:   es-module-shims

# Key-value pair of attributes to add to script tags output for the importmap.
importmap_script_attributes:

    # Example:
    # data-turbo-track:    reload

    # Prototype
    key:                  ~

# The directory to store JavaScript vendors.
vendor_dir:           '%kernel.project_dir%/assets/vendor'

UPDATE #2: Here is the output of debug:asset-mapper
php bin/console debug:asset-map

Asset Mapper Paths
------------------

 -------------------------------------------- -------------------------- 
  Path                                         Namespace prefix          
 -------------------------------------------- -------------------------- 
  vendor/symfony/ux-turbo/assets/dist          @symfony/ux-turbo         
  vendor/symfony/stimulus-bundle/assets/dist   @symfony/stimulus-bundle  
  assets                                                                 
 -------------------------------------------- -------------------------- 

Mapped Assets
-------------

 ---------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------- 
  Logical Path                                   Filesystem Path                                     
 ---------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------- 
  @symfony/ux-turbo/turbo_controller.js          vendor/symfony/ux-turbo...ist/turbo_controller.js   
  @symfony/ux-turbo/turbo_stream_controller.js   vendor/symfony/ux-turbo...bo_stream_controller.js   
  @symfony/stimulus-bundle/controllers.js        vendor/symfony/stimulus...ets/dist/controllers.js   
  @symfony/stimulus-bundle/loader.js             vendor/symfony/stimulus...e/assets/dist/loader.js   
  controllers/hello_controller.js                assets/controllers/hello_controller.js              
  styles/app.css                                 assets/styles/app.css                               
  vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.index.js            assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.index.js          
  vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css    assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css  
  vendor/@hotwired/turbo/turbo.index.js          assets/vendor/@hotwired/turbo/turbo.index.js        
  vendor/@hotwired/stimulus/stimulus.index.js    assets/vendor/@hotwired/stimulus/stimulus.index.js  
  vendor/@popperjs/core/core.index.js            assets/vendor/@popperjs/core/core.index.js          
  images/logo.png                                assets/images/logo.png                              
  bootstrap.js                                   assets/bootstrap.js                                 
  app.js                                         assets/app.js                                       
 ---------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------- 

Here's what on my project subdirectory...
$ ls
assets  compose.override.yaml  composer.lock  config         migrations        public     src           templates  translations  vendor
bin     composer.json          compose.yaml   importmap.php  phpunit.xml.dist  README.md  symfony.lock  tests      var

$ tree public

public
├── assets
│   ├── app-1ea1bfab4c9767d2a37f5882af74daad.js
│   ├── bootstrap-64a4b5ea7dbc6734045c3664743a2a98.js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── hello_controller-55882fcad241d2bea50276ea485583bc.js
│   ├── entrypoint.app.json
│   ├── images
│   │   └── logo-8d825ecbf2f8333f26db08855677ec8a.png
│   ├── importmap.json
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── styles
│   │   └── app-0e8df34d09573e7dc37a853248b222c3.css
│   ├── @symfony
│   │   ├── stimulus-bundle
│   │   │   ├── controllers-20d1514fd94d72a9c2d52e553862ddfb.js
│   │   │   └── loader-e1ee9ace0562f2e6a52301e4ccc8627d.js
│   │   └── ux-turbo
│   │       ├── turbo_controller-ce5e32dafdec0b7752f02e3e2cb25751.js
│   │       └── turbo_stream_controller-a9d0d06c48318d35cc0e0aa27ef6b2dc.js
│   └── vendor
│       ├── bootstrap
│       │   ├── bootstrap.index-c0423c99f6075e6b1cef7579b5c00d32.js
│       │   └── dist
│       │       └── css
│       │           └── bootstrap.min-1712f0378f8675ca7cd423d6262fcccf.css
│       ├── @hotwired
│       │   ├── stimulus
│       │   │   └── stimulus.index-b5b1d00e42695b8959b4a1e94e3bc92a.js
│       │   └── turbo
│       │       └── turbo.index-810f44ef1a202a441e4866b7a4c72d11.js
│       └── @popperjs
│           └── core
│               └── core.index-ceb5b6c0f9e1d3f6c78ef733facfdcda.js
├── index.php
└── test.html


What does: php bin/console config:dump framework asset_mapper return?

@JulianKoster see update above. thanks! (sorry I don't know how to format text as just plain dull  on stackoverflow, but I guess that's a different meta-issue (-: )

Many thanks for including this, looks all good to go. Just to be on the safe side, what does php bin/console debug:asset-map return? Does it list any assets as missing? Something with "Unable to find etc. etc."?

@JulianKoster no, it looks like all good (see above update). Thank you again.

Damn, this is so weird. Would there happen to be any other folder on prod that it's putting the assets in "by accident"? Maybe in a different root dir or something? I'm just guessing at this point.  Or something like public_html/assets instead of public/assets?

I can't imagine how that could be, but I've pasted in some ls and tree above. So people are gleefully using this in production with no such issue? It is bizarre.
I have tried simply changing the APP_ENV in .env between prod and dev on this server and my local machine. In both cases it's fine in dev and it's "not working" (to coin a phrase) in prod. I ~might~ try a clean start with a new project and see wtf. Then copy the little work I have done here into there (if it works).
I'm spoiled by the high quality of symfony; I expect it to work.

...and I would dig deep and figure it out if I knew how, file an issue or better yet a PR if I had the chops. But I do not.

I've been trying to read up more on this, unfortunately without success, I see more people on the web facing somewhat similar issues but so far no answers found. Maybe a straw grasping final test, have you tried going for chmod -R 777 on public  and public/assets by any chance and see if that makes a difference?

I just did try that, no luck. I am now thinking about backing up and trying a different strategy. It's not a complex site, in fact semi-static, and I just want to take advantage of dynamic templates and template inheritance for the sake of DRYness. Don't really need a Webpack wrapper, not looking for anything but asset versioning. Maybe rip out AssetMapper and try the old Asset component https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html. Or... Laravel?
Thank you again for so generously trying to help me with this.

It makes sense, the old Asset / Webpack combo always worked great for me; the configuration and build step are super easy. Chaging from AssetMapper to Webpack might take no more than an hour (hopefully :)). Sorry I couldn't help more!

Please! You've been more than kind. Actually, I read in the Symfony docs that minification and combining scripts into fewer files and transpiling is no longer really necessary, with server-side compression and parallel request processing becoming the norm. The implication being that Webpack is obsolete. And it was certainly complicated enough for people to feel a need to write higher-level wrappers like Encore and Laravel Mix. But we disgress :-)
Thank you again! If I come up with a genius solution, I'll be sure to post.

@JulianKoster I think I figured it out. It was because of an Apache mod_rewrite condition in my vhost config, needed to be either inside a Directory block or else be written as  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f , i.e., including the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}. The test was coming back false, so files that did exist were not getting served. The thing with the dev vs prod, I'm not sure it was a total illusion, but it led me down the wrong path (so to speak).
Of course, this whole question I've posted is such an embarrasment, I'll have to remove it. But I wanted to let you know.

Congrats on figuring it out! Happy its not AssetMapper being broken, but sorry for the time you lost. I hope its smooth sailing from here!
